# Displaying an Multidimensional associative array as a table in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, html-table, associative-array

I was working on associative arrays in PHP. Here I made a multiple associative array.I want to show my array in tabular form. The array is

```
<?php

$schoolDetails = array(
    //First School Details
    array(
        
        array("schoolName" => "TCS"),


        array(
            "branchName"       => "Iqbal Campus",
            "phone"            => "052-4667281",
            "numberofTeachers" => 51
        ),

        array(
            "departmentName" => "Maths",
            "HOD"            => "Mr Ali"
        ),
        array(
            "departmentName" => "Science",
            "HOD"            => "Mr Imran"
        )

    ),
    array(

        array("schoolName" => "CSS"),
        array(
            "branchName"       => "Gohdpur Campus",
            "phone"            => "052-4667281",
            "numberofTeachers" => 20
        ),
        array(
            "departmentName" => "Chemistry",
            "HOD"            => "Mr Abdullah"
        ),
        array(
            "departmentName" => "Computer",
            "HOD"            => "Mr Naeem"
        )

    ),

);
```

> The way I tried to display the data is below:

```
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>School Name</th>
                                                <th>Branch Name</th>
                                                <th>Phone Number</th>
                                                <th>Number of Teachers</th>
                                                <th>Department Name</th>
                                                <th>HOD</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tfoot>
                                            <tr>
                                            <th>School Name</th>
                                                <th>Branch Name</th>
                                                <th>Phone Number</th>
                                                <th>Number of Teachers</th>
                                                <th>Department Name</th>
                                                <th>HOD</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tfoot>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <?php  foreach ($schoolDetails as $school) {
                                                    foreach ($school as $schools) {
                                                        foreach ($schools as $key => $value) {?>
                                            <tr>
                                                            <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php }}}?>

        
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

But I do not get the result in proper rows and columns. So what shall I do to display it in an exact tabular form because I have never undergone from this sort of task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($schoolDetails as $schoolDetail) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$schoolDetail[0]["schoolName"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$schoolDetail[1]["branchName"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$schoolDetail[1]["phone"]}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$schoolDetail[1]["numberofTeachers"]}</td>";

    if(!empty($schoolDetail[3]['departmentName'])) {

        echo "<td>{$schoolDetail[2]["departmentName"]}" . ", " . "{$schoolDetail[3]["departmentName"]}</td>"; 

    } else {

        echo "<td>{$schoolDetail[2]["departmentName"]}</td>";

    }

    if(!empty($schoolDetail[3]['HOD'])) {

        echo "<td>{$schoolDetail[2]["HOD"]}" . ", " . "{$schoolDetail[3]["HOD"]}</td>"; 

    } else {

        echo "<td>{$schoolDetail[2]["HOD"]}</td>"; 
    
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you seem to add values in new rows instead of new columns:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
</tr>
```

The `<tr>`tags adds new table rows. They should be added outside the last loop.

The next issue is that you have more values for each school than you have table columns. You have more than one department for each school. How should that be displayed in the table?

```
<?php
 foreach ($schoolDetails as $school) {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>{$school[0]["Schoolname"]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$school[1]["branchName"]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$school[1]["phone"]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$school[1]["numberofTeachers"]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$school[2]["departmentName"]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$school[2]["HOD"]}</td>"; 
     echo "</tr>";
 }
```

However, the code above will only list the first department... You need to provide more information on how to display the rest...

Comment: it is missing `$school[3]` data. `departmentName` is more then 1, and not **FIT** this

Comment: I want all the departments to be listed down against its school. For Example TCS is school Name so it must show all its related departments and department's related teachers.

Answer (score 0):

@Gowire Answer is just Modify.

```
 foreach ($schoolDetails as $school) {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>{$school[0]["schoolName"]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$school[1]["branchName"]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$school[1]["phone"]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$school[1]["numberofTeachers"]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$school[2]["departmentName"]}</td>";
     echo "<td>{$school[2]["HOD"]}</td>"; 
     echo "</tr>";
     for($i=3;$i<=5;$i++){
        if(isset($school[$i])){
             echo "<tr>";
             echo "<td></td>";
             echo "<td></td>";
             echo "<td></td>";
             echo "<td></td>";
             echo "<td>{$school[$i]["departmentName"]}</td>";
             echo "<td>{$school[$i]["HOD"]}</td>"; 
             echo "</tr>"; 
        }
     }
 }
```